# Ruby 1.9 iso-8859-8-i encoding

Tags: ruby, encoding, iso-8859-1

I'm trying to create a piece of code that will download a page from the internet and do some manipulation on it. The page is encoded in iso-8859-1.

I can't find a way to handle this file. I need to search through the file in Hebrew and return the changed file to the user.

I tried to use `string.encode`, but I still get the wrong encoding.

when printing the response encoding, I get: `"encoding":{}` like its undefined, and this is an example of what it returns:

`\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd&nbsp;\ufffd\ufffd-\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd&nbsp;\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`

It should be Hebrew letters.

When I try with `final.body.encode('iso-8859-8-i')`, I get the error `code converter not found (ASCII-8BIT to iso-8859-8-i)`.

Comment: Encoding issues could be a number of different things. Could you add some more specifics, with exact steps and example of non-working code (simplified just to show your encoding issue)? Obviously it depends on input file, so just show where you load the file and what `p file_contents.encoding` outputs at that stage.

Comment: Added more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have input where Ruby or OS has incorrectly assign encoding, then conversions will not work. That's because Ruby will start with the wrong assumption and try to maintain the wrong characters when converting.

However, if you know from some other source what the correct encoding is, you can use `force_encoding` method to tell Ruby how to interpret the bytes it has loaded into a `String`. Note this alters the object in place.

E.g.

```
contents = final.body
contents.force_encoding( 'ISO-8859-8' )
puts contents
```

At this point (provided it works), you now can make conversions (to e.g. UTF-8), because Ruby has been correctly told what characters it is dealing with.

I could not find `'ISO-8859-8-I'` on my version of Ruby. I am not sure yet how close `'ISO-8859-8'` is to what you need (some Googling suggests that it may be OK for you, if the `...-I` encoding is not available).

Comment: could you tell me when this method [**`default_external=`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Encoding.html#method-c-default_external-3D) is used then ?

Comment: @Babai: Good question. It may be appropriate (although docs you linked suggested this is not called in Ruby code, due to global nature of change). Probably best is setting an encoding when opening the source in the first place, but OP did not show method used for this, so my answer is a patch based on what I can see in the question. Also, it could be that the encoding is not being sent in HTTP headers (as it should be), so the OP has no choice but to force choice of encoding somehow.

Comment: Humm.. I woun't comment against your answer.. I was just checking if this method can also be helpful.. That's it frnd :)

Comment: It seems to work! thanks for your great answer. you should put your twitter account in your bio

Comment: @Babai: No worry, I was just trying to say everything at once (character encoding is complex subject). I think `default_external=` could also be useful, especially as part of initialising a processing script. It should be used with caution though, it will change character encoding behaviour of other code used in the same script - sometimes you want this, sometimes not.